# Mysql query that returns only values that are integer

Tags: mysql

I´m trying to do a query that will return only values that are multipliers of 90, to achieve this I need to end the query with something like "WHERE FIELD IS INTEGER", but can´t find a solution anywhere. Here is the query:

```
Select 

name,
partnership_start_dat,
dateDiff("2020-03-01",DATE_FORMAT(partnership_start_dat, "%Y-%m-%d")) as "Partnerships Day",
dateDiff("2020-03-01",DATE_FORMAT(partnership_start_dat, "%Y-%m-%d")) / 90 as "Multiplier of Days"

FROM leme_account


WHERE dateDiff("2020-03-01",DATE_FORMAT(partnership_start_dat, "%Y-%m-%d")) / 90  = 1 (instead of value I need to say its integer)
```

Anyone can help?
Thanks!

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the modulo function and check for it to be zero instead:

```
select name, partnership_start_dat,
dateDiff("2020-03-01",DATE_FORMAT(partnership_start_dat, "%Y-%m-%d")) as "Partnerships Day",
dateDiff("2020-03-01",DATE_FORMAT(partnership_start_dat, "%Y-%m-%d")) / 90 as "Multiplier of Days"
FROM leme_account
WHERE mod(dateDiff("2020-03-01",DATE_FORMAT(partnership_start_dat, "%Y-%m-%d")), 90) = 0
```

That should work. I haven't tested the query, just changed the condition.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need the [modulo operation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod), sometimes called the remainder operation, to do this.

For example the value of   `270 % 90` is `0`. The value of `93%90` is `3`.

To  test whether a number is evenly divisible by 90, you use `(number % 90)  = 0`.